# Mysql query taking forever and eating too much ram

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

Below is my queries trying to load columns: Imc_code, salesman_name, sales_man_code and InvoiceTotal. I tried to do it with left join but as my data grows bulkier my code below is becoming slower. Now that my data is almost 3 million, I can't even load a single data using the code below.

Currently working on localhost and tables are using both InnoDb and Myisam engine.

Also I ran the explain on my queries displaying only 20 rows:
[image]
[image]

```
SELECT 
      pref_salesman.imc_code , pref_salesman.salesman_name, 
      pref_salesman.salesman_code, pref_debtor_trans.branch_code, 
      SUM(pref_debtor_trans.ov_amount + pref_debtor_trans.ov_discount) AS InvoiceTotal

FROM 
    pref_debtor_trans LEFT JOIN pref_voided v ON 
    v.type = pref_debtor_trans.type and v.id=pref_debtor_trans.trans_no,
    pref_debtors_master, pref_sales_orders, pref_cust_branch,pref_salesman 

WHERE 
    pref_sales_orders.order_no=pref_debtor_trans.order_
    AND pref_sales_orders.branch_code=pref_cust_branch.branch_code
    AND pref_cust_branch.salesman=pref_salesman.salesman_code
    AND pref_debtor_trans.debtor_no=pref_debtors_master.debtor_no
    AND pref_debtor_trans.tran_date >= '01-01-2017'
```

Comment: 3 million rows and what are the server specs? I think you need to do some kind of clustering now :)

Comment: What storage engine are you using? What is the configuration for the server, database, and table? Clustering or partitioning may be your best options.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, Im currently running this on my localhost for debugging, but the real deal is uploaded on a cloud web server.

Comment: @fyrye Im currently using both InnoDB and Myisame storage engine :)

Comment: localhost doesn't provide much context on server configuration. e.g. linux, windows, x86, x64, mysql version, etc, as well as configuration options for the database server. Things like `innodb_file_per_table` and applied indexes greatly affect performance.

Comment: @fyrye Ok thanks. And you did mention clustering or partitioning? I wonder if those will work even on localhost? I really need to work on localhost for now because we don't have a test server. Otherwise I cant risk meddling with the real data from the real server. Also the performance of the queries from the real server is the same with my localhost.

Comment: Please add the explain output to the question (write `explain ` directly infront of your query). Also: which tables are `ov_amount` and `ov_discount` from? Also: have you verified that your result will get you the expected value? If any table other than the table containing `ov_amount` and `ov_discount` is not 1:1, but 1:n, you will probably not get the correct sum.

Comment: [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) wouldn't be impacted by localhost as it is a table construct. I would consider changing over to `InnoDB` for all of the storage engines. There are a ton of reasons why your specific use-case is running slow, we would need a lot more info to determine where exactly the issue(s) are, for example - how long is forever to you? https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks Ive edited the post.

Comment: @fyrye I did said forever because I've waited for 3 hours and still nothing is happening and if it exceeds 3 hours my computer crashes.

Comment: Step 1 is surely to store dates as dates.

Comment: After that, please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables (but especially the first one)

Comment: Also, isn't this MariaDB?

Comment: As Strawberry noted: your date format is off. Use `'2017-01-01'`! Currently, you will get absolutely every row (as every date, converted to a varchar, will be larger than the first letter `0`). You seem to be missing an index on `pref_sales_orders(order_no)`. And as I mentioned before: if you have more than one row in `pref_sales_orders` for any `order_no`, you will get the wrong sum! If you have only 1 row, the missing index is the problem here. Also check the left join to `pref_voided`. It's optimized away (is `pref_voided.id` the primary key?), but you may want it to do something.